# Mysql Mass replace specific value multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to work out how to mass replace values from a table in mysql

In table 1 (kbb_category_description) there is a column with the "category_id" and the "name"

Say ID 1 with Kitchen Door

and in table 2 (kbb_category) there is "category_id" and "in_stock" which is a 0 or 1

What I'm trying to achieve is a query passed for the following

in kbb_category_description if the "name" = "Kitchen Door" then in kbb_category the matching "category_id" on the same row the "in_stock_ changes from 0 to 1

but given there is "Kitchen Door" is duplicated id like every instance changed from 0 to 1

Is there any way this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I am perfectly clear on what you are asking. Have you tried something like this:

```
update kbb_category as cat
join kbb_category_description as catdesc
  on cat.category_id = catdesc.category_id
set catdesc.in_stock = 1
where catdesc.in_stock = 0
  AND cat.name = 'Kitchen Door';
```

Comment: Thats nearly what im looking for but i need the "name" in table "kbb_category_description" to match "Kitchen Door" for it to update the correct "category_id" in table 2 as "in_stock"

Comment: @DavidSkinner Yeah, so just by adding cat.name = 'Kitchen Door' we will only be updating records in table 2 that have a name of "kitchen door" in table 1.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc on cat.category_id = desc.category_id set desc.in_stock = 1 wher' at line 2

Im using Mysql 5.1.69 with cent os6 and php 5.3.3

Comment: My apologies. 'desc' is reserved in mysql.

Comment: Thanks that has worked a treat now. Thanks again! with the sql having 25000 entries thats just cut days of work off